# Why does resharper say 'Catch clause with single 'throw' statement is redundant'?

Tags: exception, try-catch, resharper, rethrow

I thought throwing an exception is good practice to let it bubble back up to the UI or somewhere where you log the exception and notify the user about it.

Why does resharper say it is redundant?

```
try
{
    File.Open("FileNotFound.txt", FileMode.Open);
}
catch
{
    throw;
}
```

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Because

```
try {
    File.Open("FileNotFound.txt", FileMode.Open);
} catch {
    throw;
}
```

is no different than

```
File.Open("FileNotFound.txt", FileMode.Open);
```

If the call to `File.Open(string, FileMode)` fails, then in either sample the exact same exception will find its way up to the UI.

In that `catch` clause above, you are simply catching and re-throwing an exception without doing anything else, such as logging, rolling back a transaction, wrapping the exception to add additional information to it, or anything at all.

However,

```
try {
    File.Open("FileNotFound.txt", FileMode.Open);
} catch(Exception ex) {
    GetLogger().LogException(ex);
    throw;
}
```

would not contain any redundancies and ReSharper should not complain. Likewise,

```
try {
    File.Open("FileNotFound.txt", FileMode.Open);
} catch(Exception ex) {
    throw new MyApplicationException(
        "I'm sorry, but your preferences file could not be found.", ex);
}
```

would not be redundant.

Comment: Having a catch-and-rethrow is not quite the same as having no catch. Exception filters for every catch block between a throw site and the first successful catch will run before any `finally` blocks execute; a catch-and-rethrow will cause all `finally` blocks within it to run before any exception filters outside it are run. BTW, is resharper happy if following a catch-and-rethrow is another more general catch block which does something (so the catch-and-rethrow would serve to bypass the latter catch block)?

Answer (score 17):

Because the above statement has the same behavior as if it were not there. Same as writing:

```
File.Open("FileNotFound.txt", FileMode.Open);
```

Comment: Yes. Don't catch what you're not going to handle.

Comment: @orandov - not necesarily. You may for example catch an IOException and throw a more meaningful (from the users' perspective) exception derived from ApplicationException.

Comment: Yes.  If you're going to handle the exception put it in a try/catch.  If you don't care about the exception being thrown, don't put it in a try/catch... I think it just muddles the stack trace when it is actually handled further upstream.

Comment: @John Weldon - If you use "throw" instead of "throw ex" the stack trace will stay intact.

Comment: @Twisted: The stack trace stays intact, but if the exception wasn't handled, why catch it?

Comment: throwing an exception without doing anything, to which the question is referring, is a performance drain.  Either catch it and handle it, or don't catch it.  Don't just throw, or throw ex.

Comment: @John Weldon - Yes, I agree, just pointing out that a throw in a catch does not have to muddle the stack. Sometimes I do a try...catch for logging, log the error, then use throw to keep the stack.

Answer (score 5):

Because it's redundant.

Comment: Since when is stating the question as answer a real answer :)?

Comment: lol, I tried to add the redundancy tag twice.. but alas, it failed.

Comment: but I guess I can add redundant as well.

Answer (score 4):

Because the code in the try is already throwing the exception.

You would only want to catch and re-throw the exception if you are going to do something else in the catch block in addition to re-throwing the exception.

Answer (score 1):

You have not done any processing in the catch block, just thrown the exception again.

It warns you because there is no point in having that try...catch block there.

Also, another good tip is that "throw ex" will not preserve the stack trace but "throw" will.

Answer (score 1):

It's worth noting that while...

```
try
{
    DoSomething();
}
catch
{
    throw;
}
```

...is reduntant, the following is not...

```
try
{
    DoSomething();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    // Generally a very bad idea!
    throw ex;
}
```

This second code snippet was rife through a codebase I inherited a few projects ago and it has the nasty effect of hiding the original exception's stack trace.  Throwing the exception that you just caught in this way means that the top of the stack trace is at the `throw` level, with no mention of `DoSomething` or whatever nested method calls actually caused the exception.

Good luck debugging code that does this!

Comment: R# can be set to warn that the latter is 'probably not intended'.