# Was there a good reason for redundant try catch code in original Microsoft Membership and Role Provider code?

Tags: c#

I know that this is redundant (per [Why does resharper say 'Catch clause with single 'throw' statement is redundant'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1019237/why-does-resharper-say-catch-clause-with-single-throw-statement-is-redundant)).

```
try
{
    bla bla bla
}
catch
{
    throw
}
```

So, I'm going through the old Microsoft Membership and Role Provider code (made available since 2006 per http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/04/13/442772.aspx).  And, low and behold, the code is chock full of this redundant code.

Was there a good reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a lazy way to put a breakpoint on that `throw` line, without turning on any of the debugger features that break on all exceptions.

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft's coding standards are not the same as Resharper's. Having redundant try/catch blocks isn't wrong, its just bad style. Much of the MS source code could have plenty of positive code standard changes (much of it lacks the use of var, for example).

Comment: Are you implying that usage of var is a negative / bad programming practice?

Comment: I'm implying its a good thing. Something MS should do, but doesnt.